# How to enable and access debug logging for notebook and IPython kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm doing a small research on IPython kernel and trying to get debug logs out of it and see how it interacts with a notebook. Now it looks like the documentation and example configs shipped in my distribution is totally outdated.

### The questions

1. Where the ipython kernel log files are located?
2. How can I enable DEBUG level logging in both jupyter notebook and ipython kernel?

### What I've tried

*Please read this section before giving links to the official docs*

First I created profiles for both IPython and notebook with the following commands:

```
$ ipython profile create
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

As expected three files where created:

- .jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
- .ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py
- .ipython/profile_default/ipython_kernel_config.py

In these files I found similar commented fragments:

```
 # Set the log level by value or name.
 # c.Application.log_level = 0
```

I tried to uncomment it in the jupyter config. Instead of adding more details it totally disabled console output for the `jupyter` process. I also tried value `50` it has the same result, value `DEBUG` gave me Python error on start.

I also played with these values in ipython's configs but I wasn't able to find log files location.

In mail list command line option `--log-level=DEBUG` is mentioned and indeed it works for jupyter. But I really want to persist this setting in a profile and have debug info for the kernel too.

Config options `NotebookApp.log_level` and `IPKernelApp.log_level` also change nothing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe that this kind of functionality is still on the wishlist:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8570

But you could try something like this:

```
jupyter notebook --debug > log.file 2>&1
```

or

```
ipykernel kernel --debug > log.file 2>&1
```

Comment: how about from DOS?

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to start ipython kernel without attached frontend with option --debug:

```
ipython kernel --debug
```

You can get lot of info about interaction between kernel and the forntend by setting  `c.Session.debug = True` in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I recommend

1. Find the python bin/exe that you kernel use. You should be able to find it in your kernel file or you can see it from your jupyter notebook log. For example, from the log below, you can see that it is /opt/anaconda3/envs/ray_python39/bin/python

   [D 09:12:21.717 NotebookApp] Starting kernel: ['/opt/anaconda3/envs/ray_python39/bin/python', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-c106812b-d169-43bd-b305-159235683941.json']
2. Run the python execution using the path found in step 1. Then run your code, it will tell you exactly why the kernel failed.