# sagemaker notebook instance failed to run even a single line of code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, development-environment, amazon-sagemaker

l am running a notebook instance as usual.

But suddenly something was wrong. The notebook failed to give out anything. So l use a simple line of code to test it, which returns the following result:
[my test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6h2t.png)

The notebook even failed to run so simple a code, and the kernel is showing a 'busy' state.(right-up corner)

Simultaneously I'm running another .py file through the terminal, which works well all along.

Anyone gets an idea? Thanks for any possible reason told.

instance [instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW09e.png)

My log console
[log console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxKhy.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Can you include your image in your post (and not as links) using the [proper markdown syntax](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post) ?

Apart from that it would be helpful to include the logs of jupyter and of the kernel

Comment: sorry, but users under 10-rep aren't allowed to post a picture.  If l have to describe the picture, that is: [*]  print(1)  ,which lasts very long time and no output

Comment: alright, but still, if you want anybody to understand what is going on, we are going to need the logs

Comment: Thanks for reminding, l've included the log console in my question. l don't know why it's all blank. l've tried several times.

Comment: This question may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33632529/how-to-enable-and-access-debug-logging-for-notebook-and-ipython-kernel

Comment: (basically, run `jupyter` with the `--debug` option, and look at the output of the console)

Comment: well, seems the kernel has collapsed, no longer useful. So l reinstall another kernel and solve the problem. Thanks all for your suggestion. The method of checking logs also enlightens me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone encounters the condition in which the kernel is showing 'busy' and your can't run any code, just uninstall this kerenel and reinstall one.

Using 'conda'-related command about which you can easily find information on the Internet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).